# How to style the first and last menu item in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

How can I add some class to the first and the last item in the menu?

Comment: How are you displaying this menu? Is it a custom menu (a la WordPress 3.0) or wp_list_pages or similar? Is using `:first-child` and `:last-child` in CSS an option, given limited browser compatibility?

Comment: I tried to use these CSS pseudo-classes but it doesn't work in IE so I don't think I can use it. I use WordPress 3.0 menu feature. The best, but not very beautiful solution I found is to use regular expressions and insert my class conditionally. The other way I will try is to use jQuery. Thanks.

Comment: Questions like this should go to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Wordpress community on stackexchange is not as large as this one so I asked here. I am sure people who read wordpress.stackexchange.com also read this one.

Comment: @Andy, right. I personally don't understand wordpress.stackexchange and the whole stackexchange model, since stackoverflow still has the best Q&As ;) *kudos*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using jQuery:
Since CSS2 you can use the :first-child and :last-child selectors. For example, adjusting the margins for this menu, depending on its order:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li> <a href='/x1'>One</a> </li>
    <li> <a href='/x2'>Two</a> </li>
    <li> <a href='/x3'>Three</a> </li>
    <li> <a href='/x4'>Four</a> </li>
</ul>
```

select the menu items as such:

```
.nav > li > a { //selects ALL menu items
    padding: 20px;
}
.nav > li:first-child > a { 
    // selects the FIRST menu item, aka the first child 'li' of its parent '.nav'
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.nav > li:last-child > a { 
    // selects the LAST menu item, in this case 'Fourth'
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery solution is the easy one:

Add this to your script file:

```
$("ul li:first").addClass("first");
$("ul li:last").addClass("last");
```

Comment: Yep, I think the easiest and not so bad variant is this one so I choose this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org) has all info you need. 
But I assume that you're looking for the [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) function. However; as far as I know; it's not possible to specify a different class to only the first and last menu items.

Answer (score 0):

How are you outputting it in your template? Is the menu being added through the admin panel or manually in the template?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use jQuery's `:first` and `:last` selectors ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, which worked for me:

[Adding first / last CSS classes to menus](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/75656/13921)

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'tgm_filter_menu_class', 10, 2 );
/**
 * Filters the first and last nav menu objects in your menus
 * to add custom classes.
 *
 * This also supports nested menus.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @param array $objects An array of nav menu objects
 * @param object $args Nav menu object args
 * @return object $objects Amended array of nav menu objects with new class
 */
function tgm_filter_menu_class( $objects, $args ) {

    // Add first/last classes to nested menu items
    $ids        = array();
    $parent_ids = array();
    $top_ids    = array();
    foreach ( $objects as $i => $object ) {
        // If there is no menu item parent, store the ID and skip over the object
        if ( 0 == $object->menu_item_parent ) {
            $top_ids[$i] = $object;
            continue;
        }

        // Add first item class to nested menus
        if ( ! in_array( $object->menu_item_parent, $ids ) ) {
            $objects[$i]->classes[] = 'first-menu-item';
            $ids[]          = $object->menu_item_parent;
        }

        // If we have just added the first menu item class, skip over adding the ID
        if ( in_array( 'first-menu-item', $object->classes ) )
            continue;

        // Store the menu parent IDs in an array
        $parent_ids[$i] = $object->menu_item_parent;
    }

    // Remove any duplicate values and pull out the last menu item
    $sanitized_parent_ids = array_unique( array_reverse( $parent_ids, true ) );

    // Loop through the IDs and add the last menu item class to the appropriate objects
    foreach ( $sanitized_parent_ids as $i => $id )
        $objects[$i]->classes[] = 'last-menu-item';

    // Finish it off by adding classes to the top level menu items
    $objects[1]->classes[] = 'first-menu-item'; // We can be assured 1 will be the first item in the menu :-)
    $objects[end( array_keys( $top_ids ) )]->classes[] = 'last-menu-item';

    // Return the menu objects
    return $objects;

}
```

Credits goes to Thomas for posting the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have use following filter which add class first and last <li> item into menu

```
function wpb_first_and_last_menu_class($items) {
    $items[1]->classes[] = 'first-menu-item'; // add first class

    $cnt = count($items);
    while($items[$cnt--]->post_parent != 0); // find last li item
    $items[$cnt+1]->classes[] = 'last-menu-item'; // last item class
    return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wpb_first_and_last_menu_class'); //filter to iterate each menu
```